# google app script to add progressbar to google slides

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

[this link](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/editors/slides/quickstart/progress-bar) in developers.google.com gives a google app script to add a progressbar to a google slide. However I can't make it to work... Is it the code not working anymore? Or maybe there is something else to do besides the instructions given there? Here the code:

```
var BAR_ID = 'PROGRESS_BAR_ID';
var BAR_HEIGHT = 10; // px
var presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();

function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen();
}

function onOpen(e) {
  SlidesApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
      .addItem('Show progress bar', 'createBars')
      .addItem('Hide progress bar', 'deleteBars')
      .addToUi();
}

//Create a rectangle on every slide with different bar widths.
function createBars() {
  deleteBars(); // Delete any existing progress bars
  var slides = presentation.getSlides();
  for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; ++i) {
    var ratioComplete = (i / (slides.length - 1));
    var x = 0;
    var y = presentation.getPageHeight() - BAR_HEIGHT;
    var barWidth = presentation.getPageWidth() * ratioComplete;
    if (barWidth > 0) {
      var bar = slides[i].insertShape(SlidesApp.ShapeType.RECTANGLE, x, y,
                                      barWidth, BAR_HEIGHT);
      bar.getBorder().setTransparent();
      bar.setLinkUrl(BAR_ID);
    }
  }
}

// Deletes all progress bar rectangles.
function deleteBars() {
  var slides = presentation.getSlides();
  for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; ++i) {
    var elements = slides[i].getPageElements();
    for (var j = 0; j < elements.length; ++j) {
      var el = elements[j];
      if (el.getPageElementType() === SlidesApp.PageElementType.SHAPE &&
          el.asShape().getLink() &&
          el.asShape().getLink().getUrl() === BAR_ID) {
        el.remove();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT: what does works is running the createbars function manually. Is there a way to run this when the slides opens?

Comment: Google Slides has no installable OnOpen trigger. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) I think that by this, `createBars()` cannot be run without the error when the slides opens.

Comment: it does says presentations... are those slides?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about your replying.

Comment: ok, no problem. In the link you commented, it says that onOpen triggers works on presentations.... are presentations the same as slides? I would think so, so the onOpen in the code should work....

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could understand about your replying. In that case, Google Slides is the same with Presentations. And, Google Slides can use the simple trigger of OnOpen. But when I tested the script, it seems that `SlidesApp.getUi()` cannot be used at Google Slides. On the other hand, Spreadsheet can use `SpreadsheetApp.getUi()`. I'm not sure whether this is the bug. But I couldn't find it at the issue tracker. So for example, how about posting it as a bug or a future request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If you go on `View -> Executions`, you will see the error

```
Exception: Authorization is required to perform that action.at [unknown function](Code:3:30)
```

- This is because the content of your line 3

  ```
  var presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  ```

  **requires authorization from the user**.

- In other words, **this variable cannot be global**, but needs to defined in functions that are manually run by the user - that is both `function createBars()` and `function deleteBars()`
- Also:

  ```
  SlidesApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
  ```

  works only in Add-ons, for creating a custom menu from a bound script without installing it as an Add-on - use

  ```
  SlidesApp.getUi().createMenu("my Menu")
  ```

  instead.